# Need to show scrollbar only if more column is there in ag-grid-polymer

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid-polymer .I want to show the scrollbar only if more column is available and will hide the scrollbar if less column is available. By default Everytime scrollbar is coming in less column also.

A
Version:18.1.0
Property I have used: suppresshorizontalscrollbar :false 
I am also calling sizeToFit() ..but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

It's actually `suppressHorizontalScroll`; not `suppresshorizontalscrollbar`, and you should set it to `true`.
Reference: [Scrolling](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#scrolling)

This property doesn't work for Edge browser.
Reference: [ag-grid Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/)

> *The property suppressHorizontalScroll does not work with the browser Edge. If you are targeting Edge, then there is no way to hide the scrollbar. Currently there is no known way to hide a scroll bar in Edge. The technique ag-Grid uses is to set the CSS overflow property to 'hidden' (rather than 'auto'). In all other browsers, this technique works, however in Edge it does not.*

Comment: if i will make "suppressHorizontalScroll: true" then horizontal scrollbar will never come if there are more column also.i need horizontal scroll bar only come if more column are there